# How to send an email to the node author when a date is approaching?

Tags: 6, datetime, emails

The user has created a node and has set a future date to be alerted of the approach of this date.

I want the user receive an email when the set date is approaching.

Making the user able to change the approaching time would be great.
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tested [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), this is the module to do such actions based on events.
Here is a tutorial to help you with this: [Publish content based on a CCK date field](http://drupal.org/node/520012).

Also don't forget to enable the debugging feature of rules under `admin/rules/settings`.

Comment: Im trying it right now. 

If I understood the way it works, I am going to need to add an action "Send email" and create a trigger that will run the action isnt it?
But I need to send the email with some information that are inside the node, and I'm having trouble creating the action "Send email" with these information.

Comment: This is correct.