# Create an e-mail reminder depending on a date field in a custom content type

Tags: rules, emails, notifications

I have created a custom content in which there is a date field and an e-mail field I would like to add an automatic email reminder that is triggered on that date and sent to the email specified in the custom field.

What is the correct procedure to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an email to the node author when a date is approaching?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/how-to-send-an-email-to-the-node-author-when-a-date-is-approaching)

Comment: Well this one is about a scheduled post, I am trying to set the reminder module to send an email to a date entered in a specific date field on a custom content type post

Answer (score 1):

I followed the following instructions to achieve what I wanted to do.

> Create a Rules component of type 'Action Set' and call it 'Send Notification'. Add a Variable of 'Entity: Node', give it a label
>   and machine name of 'node'.
>
> Add an action to the loop (note: add it to the loop and not the
>   component) of 'System: Send Mail'.
>
> Add a new rule and call it 'On new event', to react on 'Node: After
>   saving new content'. Restrict it to the custom content type.
>
> Add an action to this rule, 'Rules schduler: schedule component
>   evaluation', and select the 'send notification' component you created
>   earlier.
>
> Set the evaluation date to node:field-event-date.
>
> Add an offset: -1 days (optional)
>
> Add an identifier of 'node-[node:nid]-event' and note its pattern as
>   you will be using it to delete events.
>
> Select the Node as 'node'

Source: [Send reminder to referenced users day before event date in cck date field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135381/send-reminder-to-referenced-users-day-before-event-date-in-cck-date-field/141044?noredirect=1#comment169884_141044)